# Interface Builder: Dropping a button on content view results in small font size

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsbutton

I noticed an odd behavior in Interface Builder (Xcode 4):

Dropping a plain old Push Button directly on the content view of a window results in a small button with the font "System Mini 9".

When I drop the button on a custom view I get the expected "normal" button with the font "System 13". See screenshot.

Why is that and is there a way to always get the "normal" size even when placing the button on the content view?

BTW: I tried changing the font size of the smaller button, the label changes, but the button height remains tiny.

[image: Interface Builder screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height is affected by the control size (which is an enum and not to be confused with the control’s frame size). Use the Size inspector (ruler icon) to change it to *Regular*. To do this programmatically set the `controlSize` property to `NSRegularControlSize`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the setting. Any idea why IB changes the size to mini when dropping on the content view?

Comment: It depends on the view/window type you drop the control in. It should be `NSRegularControlSize` for normal windows and `NSSmallControlSize` for utility panels. But speaking from experience IB's/Xcode's heuristics don’t always work that well.